# Can GCS "PATCH" completely replace metadata in one request

Tags: rest, http, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

According to the documentation here:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api#patch

setting:

```
"metadata": null
```

will clear the metadata, whereas setting:

```
{
  "metadata": {"NEW_KEY" : "NEW_VALUE"}
}
```

will actually add to the metadata, like so:

```
"metadata": {
  "EXISTING_KEY" : "EXISTING_VALUE",
  "NEW_KEY" : "NEW_VALUE"
}
```

Lets say I didn't want to clear the metadata, nor add key/value pairs, but instead replace the metadata field with a new set of key/value pairs. For example, lets say my current metadata was:

```
"metadata": {
  "EXISTING_KEY" : "EXISTING_VALUE"
}
```

and I sent a PATCH request like so:

```
PATCH ...

"metadata": {
  "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
  "KEY2" : "VALUE2",
  "NO_OTHER_KEYS" : "NO_OTHER_VALUES"
},
```

that should result in the metadata being:

```
"metadata": {
  "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
  "KEY2" : "VALUE2",
  "NO_OTHER_KEYS" : "NO_OTHER_VALUES"
},
```

not:

```
"metadata": {
  "EXISTING_KEY" : "EXISTING_VALUE",
  "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
  "KEY2" : "VALUE2",
  "NO_OTHER_KEYS" : "NO_OTHER_VALUES"
},
```

i.e. the old keys are gone.

Now I could achieve this in two PATCH requests, first sending:

```
"metadata": null
```

and then:

```
"metadata": {
  "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
  "KEY2" : "VALUE2",
  "NO_OTHER_KEYS" : "NO_OTHER_VALUES"
},
```

would presumably result in all the old keys being removed, but could I achieve this in one patch request?

Answer (score 0):

To delete an existing key add `"EXISTING_KEY" : null` to your patch request.

```
"metadata": {
  "EXISTING_KEY" : null
  "KEY1" : "VALUE1",
  "KEY2" : "VALUE2",
  "NO_OTHER_KEYS" : "NO_OTHER_VALUES"
},
```

Comment: In general the client may not know the existing keys. They'd need to get the metadata first in that case and then send a PATCH request. Which is two requests, and also they're non-atomic. I want to replace the metadata field in one PATCH request.

Comment: You cannot do what you want in a single PATCH request.  You can do it with a GET + PATCH if the PATCH uses `ifMetageneration`.  That may require a OCC loop, of course.

Comment: @clinton - your question demonstrated two PATCH requests. My answer shows one PATCH request. If you meant to do everything READ-MODIFY-PATCH as one request, that is not possible. Your question shows READ-MODIFY-PATCH-PATCH.

Comment: @JohnHanley yes, the preface of the question showed a way to achieve this through two requests. But the actual question is can the same be achieved in one request?

Comment: No, you cannot. The design is Read-Modify-Write. You will find that principle with many services in Google Cloud to prevent two writers from destroying each other's updates.